# Jackson: Deserializing enums

Tags: java, spring, jackson

I'm using Jackson + Spring in a REST API. One of the API calls has JSON that looks like this:

```
{
    "status": "Suspended"
}
```

where the value of "status" is mapped to a Java enum, like so:

```
public enum FeatureStatus {
    Activated(0),
    Inactivated(1),
    Suspended(2),
    Deleted(3);

    private FeatureStatus(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    private int id;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public FeatureStatus valueOf(int id) {
        switch(id) {
            case 1: return Inactivated;
            case 2: return Suspended;
            case 3: return Deleted;
            default: return Activated;
        }
    }

    @JsonCreator
    public static FeatureStatus fromValue(String status) {
        if(status != null) {
            for(FeatureStatus featureStatus : FeatureStatus.values()) {
                if(featureStatus.toString().equals(status)) {
                    return featureStatus;
                }
            }

            throw new IllegalArgumentException(status + " is an invalid value.");
        }

        throw new IllegalArgumentException("A value was not provided.");
    }
}
```

However, this exception gets thrown: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: { is an invalid value.` It looks like it's not deserializing the JSON at all. My controller method has this definition:

```
public @ResponseBody void updateFeatureStatusById(@PathVariable long featureId, @RequestBody FeatureStatus updated) {
```

Any other controller automatically deserializes the JSON fine as expected using this format. How can I deserialize this JSON into my enum?

Comment: You're right, I edited the question to add the missing quotes.

Comment: _Any other controller automatically deserializes the JSON fine_ Same input and the output is as expected? I mean they both have `@RequestBody` accepting an enum like above?

Comment: I mean if any other object is deserialized with `@RequestBody`, it works as expected. There are no other enums (thus far).

Comment: I would recommend debugging, putting a breakpoint at the `fromValue()` method, and checking the methods in the stack trace to see why it's only passing `{` as the argument for `status`.

Comment: This seems to be a bug in the way JSON creator methods are invoked. You can create a wrapper class to get around the problem in the meantime.

Comment: I had the same problem times ago. My solution was to get the value as a String and then convert to the Enum Object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put this class next to your controller:

```
final class FeatureStatusJsonObject {
     public FeatureStatus status;
}
```

And then in the controller method use this:

```
@RequestBody FeatureStatusJsonObject updated
```

and get the real FeatureStatus by

```
updated.status
```

This makes the conversion from a JSON object to an Enum literal explicit in your code, and allows you to use the regular Enum <-> String (de)serialization elsewhere (if necessary).

On an unrelated note, this looks a bit funky:

```
@ResponseBody void
```

I would just make it void.

Answer (score 2):

Is the *exact* JSON you pass an Object? Enums except either JSON String or number, not Object.
If you need to give an object, you should map it to something like:

```
public class EnumWrapper {
  public FeatureStatus status;
}
```

and it'll work.